# How can I use float-left and vertical-align top both together?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use float left and vertical-align top both together.I have
div of 1000px by 1000px. I want to set 7 images as I shown in
picture.
[I want this kind of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlKxI.png)

[With this code I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjWch.png)

```
<style>
        .container{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 1000px;
     
        
        
        }
        .img{
        /* vertical-align: top; */
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
  

        }
        </style>
   </head> 
   <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src="4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src="5.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src="6.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src="7.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

```
I tried to use  vertical-align: top; 
    display: inline-block; both together but it didn't work.
```

Comment: you can use grid or flexbox instead using float.

Comment: I will add images dynamically of different sizes. Will grid work?

Comment: Yes just try to code, if you get errors or problems ask here posting code

Comment: I tried with .container{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 1000px;
        display:grid
    }
but still not working.

Comment: This question is closed, i'll suggest you to study how grid works and then try to code